# Debugging hanged windows form

Tags: .net, windows, debugging

We've a problem with a .net 4.5 windows form app which internally uses some native dlls, it's compiled as x86.

It works without any problem on x86 windows 7 machine but when we tried to run it on an x64 windows 10 machine (always compiled as x86) after some hours/days it hangs, the ui stops responding and all the worker threads seem freezed (no logs are written).

From the logs files and windows events no error/exception has been thrown, there're only events about the ui process that aren't responsive.
Using Process Explorer on the ui process the ".net assemblies" tab is empty and the .Net PErformance -> AppDomains is empty too, there're 119 contentions but the current queue length and queue length peak are 0.
If I try to attach to the hanged process with visual studio I cannot see anything (no threads, no tasks, no modules).

If I create the dump file I can open it with my local visual studio but I can't understand the problem, I suspect that the main thread is deadlocked but I'm not very good on debugging this low level problem.

Can somebody help me on debugging this issue?  I've attached the stack of the main thread from the dump file

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. you should be more precise in your question to maximize the chance to have a valuable answer. See [ask]

Comment: You haven't provided any  useful information. If Windows Forms applications had issues with Windows 10, thousands of people would have noticed. Handing means there's a problem with the code. You won't see anything in PE or Taskman precisely because it's hanged. You can *debug* it and see what's going on. You can attach a debugger and see where it stopped

Comment: `after some hours/days it hangs` what does that mean? That the same form remains open for days, even though no-one is logged in? What does the application do? Could it be that it exhaused eg its GDI resources because it doesn't dispose GDI objects properly? What about memory usage? Garbage collections? `catch{}` clauses that hide errors?

Comment: BTW if you want to animate the UI you should use WPF and its transitions instead of trying to handle redrawing yourself.

Comment: It deadlocks on the critical section that protects the default process heap.  Heap corruption and "some native dlls" are forever connected.  The deadlock can occur when such a DLL is unwise enough to catch an access violation exception while trying to allocate/free.  Or when the heap is so corrupted that it gets stuck in an endless loop while traversing the heap blocks.  You can't find the cause in the minidump, only its consequence. Try to flush the bug out with the Application Verifier utility, having a decent way to trigger the bug so you don't have to wait for days tends to be important.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as i have already said i tried to attach with debugger but i didn't get any info (no threads available), using the dump i got the stack trace within the attached image. I inherith that app only for maintenance, i don't know how it use GDI resources. It's an app always running , but on win 10 x64 after it started it stops working after a few hours, sometimes even days. it didn't happen in windows 7